# add link to Actions in Django Admin

Tags: python, django, python-3.x, django-admin

In  Django admin I have a print button that sends information to the template. I want to add to the `Action` dropdown link where I checkboxes select the desired entries and in `Action` dropdown choose 
`Print`.
But when I added a link to the `Aсtion` dropdown I get an error about getting the third argument. I can not understand that this is the third argument.

**admin.py**

```
@admin.register(Salary)
class SalaryAdmin (admin.ModelAdmin):
    list_display = ('worker', 'salary_uah', 'dates', 'button')
    search_fields = ('worker', 'salary_uah', 'dates')
    list_filter = ('worker', 'date')
    actions = ['button']

    def button(self, obj):
        return '<a class="button" href="{}">Print</a>'.format(reverse('act', args=[obj.pk]))

    button.short_description = 'Actions'
    button.allow_tags = True
```

**urls.py**

```
urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^$',home, name='home'),
    url(r'^add/$',add_worker, name='add'),
    url(r'^act/(?P<obj>[\w-]+)$',acts, name='act')
]
```

**models.py**

```
class Salary (models.Model):
    worker = models.ForeignKey(Worker)
    salary_uah = models.IntegerField ('Salary')
    date = models.DateTimeField('Date', default=datetime.datetime.utcnow())
```

**views.py**

```
def acts (request, obj):
    if not request.user.is_authenticated():
        return redirect('admin:login')
    salary = Salary.objects.get(id=obj)
    workers = Worker.objects.filter(id=salary.worker.pk).values()
    salary = Salary.objects.filter(id=obj).values()
    return render(request, 'zpapp/act.html', {'workers':workers, 'salary':salary })
```

**error message :**

```
TypeError at /admin/zpapp/salary/
button() takes 2 positional arguments but 3 were given
```

Could you help me add a link in Action ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you are on the wrong track here. Actions are only supposed to be a text that will be added to the drop down automatically by django. An HTML link AFAIK isn't supported here. Further:

> First, we’ll need to write a function that gets called when the action
>   is triggered from the admin. Action functions are just regular
>   functions that take three arguments:
>
> The current ModelAdmin An HttpRequest representing the current
>   request, A QuerySet containing the set of objects selected by the
>   user. Our publish-these-articles function won’t need the ModelAdmin or
>   the request object, but we will use the queryset:

Source:

Your action if it's to be usable at all, needs to be

```
def button(self, request, queryset):
```

If on the other hand what you want is to add an HTML button to a list view or an edit view, you need to modify the admin template.